# Why does xdg-open remove @ from a URI if it's the first character in the path?

Tags: url, xdg-open

I'm trying to get xdg-open to properly handle URIs with the pattern of ob://@username but it seems that xdg-open is stripping the @ symbol. Is there someway to prevent this without modifying xdg-open itself?

My `openbazaar.desktop` file consists of the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=OpenBazaar Client
Exec=openbazaar "%u"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/ob
```

If I put a character before the @ (i.e. ob://a@username) it doesn't remove it. I've verified that it's not an issue with running `openbazaar ob://@username` so I'm wondering if there's something I can do in the .desktop file to prevent it from doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xdg-open` is attempting to comply with the standards...

An **`@`** mark is a delimiter between user- and host-names, and without the user-name it is unexpected (and not standard).  If you want to use it in a different way, you will have to encode it.

Further reading:

- [Clarification of Proper Use of "@" (at sign) in URI-style Components](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-accilent-at-sign-00.html)
- [Can I use an at symbol (@) inside URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509028/can-i-use-an-at-symbol-inside-urls/19737890)

Comment: Good one!  I was reading the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396) and finding the use of `@` ambiguous, not a surprise they published a clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like I'll have to take an alternate route. I tried encoding @ to %40 but I get an error stating that it's a malformed URL.